# I don't understand how "?" is being used here

Tags: php, postgresql, syntax

So, I have this PHP code:

```
$tabid = getTabid($module);
if($tabid==9)
  $tabid="9,16";
$sql = "select * from field ";
$sql.= " where field.tabid in(?) and";
```

Now, how exactly does the `?` work here? I vaguely understand that in PHP, `?:` is a ternary operator, but the colon isn't being used here, and `?` is part of a Postgresql query anyway.

The final query looks a bit like this:

```
select * from field where field.tabid in('9,16')
```

So, the question mark is replaced by the contents of $tabid, how does that happen?

The issue is that `('9,16')` is not accepted by Postgres as an integer, it needs to be written like `(9,16)`, so how do I do that? How do I remove the apostrophes?

Thanks a lot for the help, have a good day!

edit: More code was requested:

```
$sql.= " field.displaytype in (1,2,3) and field.presence in (0,2)";
```

followed by if statements, I think this is the relevant one:

```
if($tabid == 9 || $tabid==16)
{
    $sql.= " and field.fieldname not in('notime','duration_minutes','duration_hours')";
}
$sql.= " group by field.fieldlabel order by block,sequence";
$params = array($tabid);
//Running the query.
$result = $adb->pquery($sql, $params);
```

Oh, I think I see now, I think it is a place holder, a part of the pquery function:

```
function pquery($sql, $params, $dieOnError=false, $msg='') {
  Stuff
  $sql = $this->convert2Sql($sql, $params);
  }
```

Now, this is where it seems to get fun, here's part of the convert2Sql function:

```
function convert2Sql($ps, $vals) {
   for($index = 0; $index < count($vals); $index++) {   
        if(is_string($vals[$index])) {
            if($vals[$index] == '') {
                $vals[$index] = "NULL";
            }
            else {
                $vals[$index] = "'".$this->sql_escape_string($vals[$index]). "'";
            }
        } 
    }
    $sql = preg_replace_callback("/('[^']*')|(\"[^\"]*\")|([?])/", array(new PreparedQMark2SqlValue($vals),"call"), $ps); 

    return $sql;
}
```

The problem I think lies in the
`$vals[$index] = "'".$this->sql_escape_string($vals[$index]). "'";` line.
The `sql_escape_string($str)` function just returns `pg_escape_string($str)`.

Sorry for the super long edit, but I still haven't been able to get past I am afraid, thanks for all the help!

Edit 2: I fixed the problem, all it took was changin `$tabid = "9,16"` to `$tabid = array(9,16)`. I have no idea why, oh and I also had to remove the group by statement because Postgresql requires every field to be placed in that statement.

Comment: can you please show us the code that following? That is propably a placeholder for the query.

Comment: are you using some kinf of ORM?? we would need the code that is used to get the result.. i.e command.RunQuery or something and the code preceding it..

Comment: See [the paragraph on Parameterized statements in the Wikipedia article on SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) and [the Wikipedia article on Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen: yeah I thought the 'how does it work here' was the question too, initially. On reading the question further you will find that the OP knew that, but doesn't know how to pass a list of values for a single placeholder

Comment: @sehe - Agreed; no vote to close on my part. Just meant as a "interesting further reading" comment :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos I added more code, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a positional parameter for a prepared statement

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

You don't actually 'remove' the quotes, you have to pass SQL array of ints instead of a string value into the parameter when doing `pg_execute`

An example:

```
// Assume that $values[] is an array containing the values you are interested in.
$values = array(1, 4, 5, 8);

// To select a variable number of arguments using pg_query() you can use:
$valuelist = implode(', ', $values);

// You may therefore assume that the following will work.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN ($1)';
$result = pg_query_params($query, array($valuelist))
     or die(pg_last_error());
// Produces error message: 'ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer'
 // It only works when a SINGLE value specified.
```

Instead you must use the following approach:

```
$valuelist = '{' . implode(', ', $values . '}'
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = ANY ($1)';
$result = pg_query_params($query, array($valuelist));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, you are right, it is a positional parameter, I am still trying to make sense of it all, the functions that deal with the replacing are a bit above my head, but I shall respond soon!

Comment: Forgive me, I am not quite sure what you were suggesting, I sort of tried out what you were suggesting, but I think the code is written in a slightly different way, namely in that pg_query_params is not used, but rather a function that does the replacing instead. I wrote a slightly wordy edit up above, if you have time, could you give it a quick skim through, thanks a lot for your help.